# quadratic programming in R matrix form

Tags: r, quadratic-programming

I'm using `R` software `quadprog`. [image]

to solve the following optimization:

```
Dmat <- matrix(c(1,1.5,1.5,5),nrow=2,ncol=2)
dvec <- c(0.5,0)
Amat <- -matrix(c(3,15,2,-3),nrow=2,ncol=2)
bvec <- matrix(c(-2,1),nrow=2,ncol=1)

solve.QP(Dmat,dvec,Amat,bvec)
```

the solution that I get from solving the above problem is:

```
$`solution`
[1] -0.2307692  0.1794872

$value
[1] 0.1604208
```

The correct solution is

```
$`par`
[1] -0.8064516  0.2096774

$value
[1] -0.04032258
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to:

- double `Dmat`
- negate `dvec`
- transpose `Amat`
- negate `bvec`

That is:

```
Dmat <- matrix(c(2,3,3,10),nrow=2,ncol=2)
dvec <- c(-0.5,0)
Amat <- -matrix(c(3,15,2,-3),nrow=2,ncol=2,byrow=TRUE)
bvec <- -matrix(c(-2,1),nrow=2,ncol=1)
```

---

```
> solve.QP(Dmat,dvec,Amat,bvec)
$solution
[1] -0.8064516  0.2096774

$value
[1] -0.04032258
```